# SSRS 2014 Repead Header Row and Parent Group Name

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Hello I want to design a Report that displays each  Group2 on a seperate Page repeating the parent Group1 Value and the Report Header.

Below is a query i used to test this.

I tried to set to set FixedData, RepeatOnNewPage, etc.
Did i miss something?

`SELECT 'Main' AS Group1, 'Sub' AS Group2, 'Detail' AS GroupDetail, 1 AS Price
UNION
SELECT 'Main' AS Group1, 'Sub2' AS Group2, 'Detail' AS GroupDetail, 1 AS Price
UNION
SELECT 'Main' AS Group1, 'Sub2' AS Group2, 'Detail2' AS GroupDetail, -1 AS Price
UNION
SELECT 'Main' AS Group1, 'Sub2' AS Group2, 'Detail2' AS GroupDetail, 1 AS Price
UNION
SELECT 'Main2' AS Group1, 'Sub3' AS Group2, 'Detail3' AS GroupDetail, 1 AS Price
UNION

SELECT 'Main2' AS Group1, 'Sub4' AS Group2, 'Detail3' AS GroupDetail, 1 AS Price
UNION

SELECT 'Main2' AS Group1, 'Sub4' AS Group2, 'Detail4' AS GroupDetail, -1 AS Price
UNION

SELECT 'Main2' AS Group1, 'Sub4' AS Group2, 'Detail4' AS GroupDetail, 1 AS Price`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
KeepWithGroup: After 
RepeatOnNewPage: True
```

those to settings on the head row and the girst group did the trick

Source:
Case 2:  One Row Group – Column Headings in a Header Row – Repeating Does NOT Work
http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2011/8/20/repeating-column-headers-on-every-page-in-ssrs-doesnt-work-o.html